# How to fix iterated inheritance of abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with iterated inheritance of abstract classes in c++.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
    Base() {}
    virtual int foo(const char* x, int z) = 0;
    virtual int foo(int y, int z) = 0;
    int bar(int a, char b);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    Derived() {}
    int foo(const char* x, int z);
    int foo(int y, int z);
    int bar(int a, char b);
};

int Derived::foo(const char* x, int z) {
    cout << "Derived::foo(const char*, int)" << endl;
    return foo(100, 80);
}

int Derived::foo(int y, int z) {
    cout << "Derived::foo(int, int)" << endl;
    return bar(10, 'c');
}

int Derived::bar(int a, char b) {
    cout << "Derived::bar(int, char)" << endl;
    return 0;
}

class Derived2 : public Derived {
    public:
    Derived2() : Derived() {}
    int foo(const char* x, int z);
    int foo(int y, int z);
    int bar(int a, char b);
};

int Derived2::foo(const char* x, int z) {
    cout << "Derived2::foo(const char*, int)" << endl;
    return Derived::foo(x, z);
}

int Derived2::foo(int y, int z) {
    cout << "Derived2::foo(int, int)" << endl;
    return Derived::foo(y, z);
}

int Derived2::bar(int a, char b) {
    cout << "Derived2::bar(int, char)" << endl;
    return Derived::bar(a, b);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Derived2 cl;
    cl.foo("Hello", 80);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Derived2::foo(const char*, int)
Derived::foo(const char*, int)
Derived2::foo(int, int)
Derived::foo(int, int)
Derived::bar(int, char)
```

The problem is that, when I call `foo(100, 80)` inside `Derived::foo(const char*, int)` function, instead of `Derived::foo(int, int)`, `Derived2::foo(int, int)` will be called and that's not what I want.

I want `Derived::foo(int, int)` to be called directly. So in the output code, the third line must not appear.
I don't know why it happens, also because in Derived class I've not declared virtual methods.

Note: In Base class I've declared `int bar(int, char)` and when inside function `Derived::foo(int, int)` I call `bar(10, 'c')`, `Derived::bar(int, char)` will be called instead of `Derived2::bar(int, char)` and that's what I want.

Also tried with `this` keyword but doesn't work.

A solution I found is to call `Derived::foo(int, int)` inside `Derived::foo(const char*, int)` function, but it isn't so pretty.

Obviously I don't want to modify the Base class. (bar function is only an example).

Runned with Repl.it

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: in `Derived2::foo` you call `Derived::foo(y, z);`, ie the fully qualified method, why dont you try the same in `Derived::foo` ?

Comment: btw i find it rather questionable to use inheritance when you dont want to inherit the methods. It seems like you dont need inheritance at all (maybe for something not included in the example)

Comment: Any function declared `virtual` in any base class will be `virtual` in any derived classes whether you use `virtual` keyword or not... Other than that you already know solution, there is no other.

Comment: I look into your Derived:Foo implementation and I do not see it includes a call to foo, in contrary to what you have written ("The problem is that, when inside 'Derived::foo(const char*, int)' function, I call 'foo(y, z)')

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 and @sklott thank you for your explanation. In fact I don't want to "override" Base methods, but "mask" them. In my project I can choose whetever to use Derived or Derived2 class based on need (think as they were "levels of security measures"). So I'm searching a method that does not override Derived's functions. I want to call `Derived::foo(int, int)` from `Derived::foo(const char*, int)` directly, without passing through Derived2' functions. Also I want to maintein functions' names equal as it were an override. Don' know if I explained myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `cl` is an object of class `Derived2`, a call to any `foo` will default to that class's implementation of `foo` instead of the implementation in it's base class.

In other words, when the call to `Derived::foo(const char*, int)` originates in `cl`, `Derived2::foo(int, int)` will always be picked over `Derived::foo(int, int)`.

A simple solution in this case would be to rewrite to:

```
int Derived::foo(const char* x, int z) {
    cout << "Derived::foo(const char*, int)" << endl;
    return Derived::foo(100, 80);
}

int Derived::foo(int y, int z) {
    cout << "Derived::foo(int, int)" << endl;
    return Derived::bar(10, 'c');
```

Comment: Ok, understood. So the solution is the one I said in my question, but it isn't so pretty. Do you think there are no other solutions?

Comment: Well, the thing is: if your structure is the way you had it, it's _supposed_ to choose the function implementation in the derived class over that of the base class.

If that's not your intended behavior, then you should consider another structure altogether.

Comment: Another solution is to not declare funcions as virtual pure, but declare them (non-virtual) without body. So no function is overridden and works as I want. If I try to call `Base::foo(int, int)` for example I've a compilation error, so it's all. The only thing is that `Base` class is not abstract as usual.